# Component for SaaS Provisioning Service

Tags: cloud-foundry, provisioning, saas

How do I find out the component of saas registry. I tried to refer help document from the sap portal and could not able to find it. I'm looking for some pointers with respect to this, any idea on this will be helpful, thanks in advance.